# ¿Existe alguna forma de convertir un arreglo (array) tipo char en un arreglo tipo int en C++?

Tags: c++, array

Es requerido que la entrada de mi programa sea una sola línea en la que el usuario ingrese una palabra y luego separado por espacios una serie de números (ilimitados).

Actualmente leo la línea con un cin utilizando la libreria #include<string.h>, sin embargo esto solo me sirve para lograr guardar toda la línea que el usuario ingresa en un arreglo de tipo char:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char array[100];
cin.getline(array,100,'\n');

return0
}
```

Necesito poder dividir el array de tipo char que ingresa el usuario en dos arreglos distintos donde uno me guarde la palabra ingresada por el usuario y el otro que sea tipo int guarde los números.

***Espero ser mas clara de esta manera, gracias.***

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si por supuesto.. que fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: Demuestra tu interés, y enséñanos que has intentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un *stream* de texto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char letras[] = "9 10 11 12 13 14 15";
    std::vector<int> numeros;

    std::stringstream stream{letras};
    int numero;

    // Mientras hayamos leído un número...
    while (stream >> numero)
        // ... guarda el número en el vector
        numeros.push_back(numero);

    for (const auto &n: numeros)
        std::cout << n << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LTsMwEEXXma@4aiWaLqhqHguSkB@pEDKuaSySceQHXVT99hDjVCzYzEgzc84dNY73qpd8mqa1YdXHo0ZjrA9Oy6Glv5n/P/rWKljXEhkOGKThcksXKlQnHXodnPSHN7xi9QKxhxAQDxCPEE8Qz6uaCh@OVZUdzWxowXHQzvqalt2caPiUc5HbJXuvM55CM5GAc2d6jXI5bm@yLRXFot2N0XfvH1J9lcsucZ/WoVSWfYCMweKOq9sfif39Q9kY0DTgVDbYJM7pEB1jX9N1mn4A)</kbd>.

Comment: Gracias por contestar! pero e intentado usar el código en otro compilador y no a funcionado, no se exactamente porque aunque imagino que es debido a que yo utilizo devc++.

Comment: @2mitadesdeunmismo Sugerencia: siempre que uno diga `no ha funcionado`, hay que decir **cómo** ha fallado (logs, mensajes, etc). Decir No funciona no da ninguna pista de lo que puede pasar. Edita tu pregunta y **añade** lo que pasó al intentar usar esta respuesta

Comment: El programa dice que la línea 10 y 18 presentan los siguientes errores:  
10. [Advertencia] listas de inicializador extendidas solo disponibles con -std = c ++ 11 o -std = gnu ++ 11
10. [Error] en C ++ 98 'stream' debe ser inicializado por el constructor, no por '{...}'
18. Los bucles "for" basados ​​en rangos de [Error] no están permitidos en el modo C ++ 98

Comment: @2mitadesdeunmismo La advertencia te está diciendo exactamente cuál es el problema:  estás compilando en modo 1998 y te dice que debes compilar en modo 2011 o superior. Por cierto, estamos en 2020, no tiene sentido compilar en un modo de hace 22 años.